# SQL Server Trigger fires unexplainably

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I've got a trigger on a table. It's a very simple trigger, set to after insert, send me an e-mail. Since I've put that trigger on, I've been sent e-mails by the system every 5 or 6 minutes or so. There is just one problem.
Whenever I receive an e-mail, the table is EMPTY

Here is my trigger

```
USE [didaprod]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Caseplayer_CaseId_Restore_insert_mail]    Script Date: 09-08-2016 11:59:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE trigger [dbo].[Caseplayer_CaseId_Restore_insert_mail] on [dbo].[Caseplayer_CaseId_Restore]

AFTER INSERT
as

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    declare @tekst nvarchar(500);

    set @tekst = 'caseid sat til null på caseplayer! Tjek Caseplayer_CaseId_Restore tabel!' + convert(varchar,getdate(),105);

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'Mail',
                                @recipients = 'kk@byggeevaluering.dk',
                                @subject = 'CASEID SAT TIL NULL!!!',
                                @body = @tekst

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

I've tried to manually insert a row, or a couple of rows in the table, just to check, and yes, the trigger fires as well, when there is a proper insert. But I cannot explain why I keep receiving the e-mails!. As for the table itself, it's got nothing fancy.

```
USE [didaprod]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Caseplayer_CaseId_Restore]    Script Date: 09-08-2016 12:04:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Caseplayer_CaseId_Restore](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CaseId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TimeOfChange] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I've disabled the trigger now, and confirmed that the e-mails have stopped. But this seems like an almost magic problem for me, and I would love to get an answer.

Suppose I do

```
delete from [Caseplayer_CaseId_Restore]
```

And just leave the table alone.
I'll still get e-mails from the system, telling me to check the table. When I then perform a

```
select * from [Caseplayer_CaseId_Restore]
```

The table is **empty**

Comment: Is this table processed by any other SPs? Is it possible that some other functionality checks for any rows in this table, processes and finally removes them?

Comment: It's a completly new table. Nothing interacts with it, except I've got a trigger on another table called "CasePlayers", that will insert rows into my "restore" table, whenever a certain criteria is met. This I have tested, and performs as expected. This whole thing is due to a legacy system we have, that tries to commit suicide once in a while, resetting a certain field in the caseplayers table every now and then. My trigger on caseplayers, just insert what is needed to perform a restore, in my restore table, so I don't have to resort to backups, but can make a quick statement instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server triggers fire once per *statement* rather than once per *row*. That's why it's important to write triggers that use `inserted` appropriately, to deal with the fact that it may contain 1, many, or **zero** rows.

I suspect that it's the latter case here. (I.e. a regularly executed INSERT statement that is in fact inserting zero rows)

So, you might want something like:

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[Caseplayer_CaseId_Restore_insert_mail]
            on [dbo].[Caseplayer_CaseId_Restore]

AFTER INSERT
as

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF EXISTS(select * from inserted)
    BEGIN
      declare @tekst nvarchar(500);

      set @tekst = 'caseid sat til null på caseplayer! Tjek Caseplayer_CaseId_Restore tabel!' + convert(varchar,getdate(),105);

      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'Mail',
                                @recipients = 'kk@byggeevaluering.dk',
                                @subject = 'CASEID SAT TIL NULL!!!',
                                @body = @tekst

    END
```

Comment: I understand as much, and wouldn't mind getting an e-mail for each statement. What I'm experiencing, is rather closer to "magic" in my mind. Updating my question

Comment: @KasparKjeldsen - but the point I'm making is that if someone has written `INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE 0=1` (or just any select statement that happens to return no rows), the `INSERT` trigger fires - but no rows have been added.

Comment: I think I understand your point now. I'm sorry for not getting it at first. I'll give your solution a try.

Comment: Worked like a charm, again sorry I just had to wrap my mind around it. Accepted your answer.